# awk sum column based on matching header pattern

Tags: awk

I am having a file with ~10,000 columns and ~20,000 rows in the following format

```
Id  A_1 A_2 A_3 B_2 B_5 C_1
T1  0   1   1   6   1   0
T2  1   1   1   0   0   1
T3  2   0   3   1   1   5
T4  1   1   1   2   3   1
```

In the header row, 1st column is the id. From 2nd column onward are the sample name in the following format sampleName_batch#. Now, I want to add all the values for the id's based on the sampleName and have the sampleName and the sum up value in the output. My expected output is

```
Id  A   B   C
T1  2   7   0
T2  3   0   1
T3  5   2   5
T4  3   5   1
```

I have came across this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569615/combine-columns-in-one-file-by-matching-header but i dont know how to modify the whole header row.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am trying to edit solution mentioned in OP's post from cross site, its a bit tweak in solution and all lines are same as it is from it. I am NO where near in knowledge like "THE Ed Morton" in `awk`, so humbly taking his permission(I hope he is ok with it) trying to edit his great solution from cross site, could you please try following.

```
awk '
NR==1 {
    for (inFldNr=2; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        sub(/_.*/,"",$inFldNr)
        fldName = $inFldNr
        if ( !(fldName in fldName2outFldNr) ) {
            outFldNr2name[++numOutFlds] = fldName
            fldName2outFldNr[fldName] = numOutFlds
        }
        outFldNr = fldName2outFldNr[fldName]
        out2inFldNrs[outFldNr,++numInFlds[outFldNr]] = inFldNr
    }

    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        outFldName = outFldNr2name[outFldNr]
        printf "%s%s", outFldName, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    next
}
{
    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        sum = 0
        for (inFldIdx=1; inFldIdx<=numInFlds[outFldNr]; inFldIdx++) {
            inFldNr = out2inFldNrs[outFldNr,inFldIdx]
            sum += $inFldNr
        }
        printf "%s%s", sum, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
'  Input_file
```

***What is added in already existing Ed's code:***

1. Add a `sub` function to substitute everything after `_` in first line(header).
2. Removed `\t` as delimiter since OP's samples are NOT tab delimited.

Comment: Nice job on the enhancement!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my bad for asking you again. What will be the way to do if I am having seven columns of id instead of one column? Thanks

Comment: @Ashi, Hello Ashi, I am sorry I didn't get it, could you please do let me know if this is a new question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I just edit the question for a modified input file.

Comment: @Ashi, ohh please don't edit OLD question as it will confuse everyone. Kindly revert changes on this question and open a new question for your requirements thank you.

Comment: Thank I revert to the old one.